# Add Objective-C Cocoapod to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

There is an awesome Objective-C pod ([this](https://github.com/kevin-hirsch/KVNProgress)) i want to implement in my project but i don't get it to work.

As i understood i need to:

1. Download the pod

```txt
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'KVNProgress'
```

2. Create a Objective-C Header File

```txt
#import <KVNProgress/KVNProgress.h>
```

3. Set 'Objective-C Bridging Header' under Application > Build Settings

Thats all but i don't understand why this isn't working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great after a half day of testing and 4 minutes after asking my question i got it, thx for helping me. ;D

My problem was to add a...

```
import KVNProgress
```

... in my swift File.